# Input protection / load switch isn't working as intended (seeing 8.6 V on 3.3 V interface)

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, diodes, schematics

I created the following schematic and implemented it on a PCB, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended.

Expected outcome is that if I have 12 V attached to the system, I won't be able to see ANY voltage on the BAT or 3V3in lines. Currently, if 12 V is attached to the system I see ~8.6 V on BAT (average, not max.)!

[image: Aforementioned Schematic]

I'm using [PMEG2010ER](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Schottky-Barrier-Diodes-SBD_Nexperia-PMEG2010ER-115_C82288.html) Schottky barrier diodes.

Could my selection be at fault? Any and all input on how to fix this, or do it better in the future, would be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't the leakage available over schottky diodes be sufficient? (Figure 5.) What kind of load do you place on BAT when measuring an 8.6 average voltage? Just the voltmeter load? Or something else?

Comment: According to the datasheet, it looks to me like the reverse leakage through that diode could be as much as 1mA. You'd need a pulldown no greater than 3k3 to guarantee no more than 3.3V.

Comment: These diodes are trimmed for very low forward voltage at the price of beeing very leaky.

Comment: Thank you all for your input! When I measured 8.6 average on BAT I had the battery pack removed, so there was no load on BAT. (was afraid to put batteries back on the terminal with a pack there, as I was worried the alkaline cells would back-charge and rupture.

Comment: Thing is, I'm trying to be sensitive to leakage currents as this is a battery operated device. Efficiency from BAT to my load needs to be high, 12V side can be leaky, but I can't allow nearly any current to flow back through BAT lest they harm my batteries.

Comment: If anyone has another more low-power friendly (and safer) implementation i.e with a proper load switch IC, please let me know!

Comment: Based on brhans comment, I'd say an N-channel MOSFET in series with the 3.3 k resistor so that it's only bleeding of current when 12 V is present.

Comment: Did you doublecheck polarity of diode D4? In other words: what does the system do when you only apply bat voltage? And can you measure the 12V input?

Comment: @RemyHx I did double check the polarity yes, seemed it was correct in the way it's implemented.

Comment: @OskarSkog that's a good idea on how to avoid excessive leakage, I was worried about using a smaller resistor size for that reason, but that should solve it. 

The central issue still remains however, does someone have any suggestions for better diodes to use in this situation? I feel like the component choice is the issue here

Comment: So the answer here is a bit strange, I had some one else go over the circuit with me, and as far as we could determine, the issue was that the diodes just weren't doing anything for some reason. I'll be swapping them out for new ones on the next design, otherwise that should work.